# C# Label Line in Chart with Time : X and Y Axes are Positional Data Points

Tags: c#

I am plotting on a chart. I have a list that has many data points for X, Y, Z, Velocity, Acceleration, Gs, Azimuth, Etc. I have plotted the position data points X and Y, but I would like to label the plotted line with time. I have gone through the options that I think would help but have had no success scrolling through them and trying the ones I thought might work.

I apologize for the broken up code, but the code is on a closed network. I cannot show everything here.

```
chart1.Series.Add("V1Pos");  

{    
 chart1.Series["V1Pos"].Points.AddXY(vehicle1[bytYPosition][i], vehicle1[bytXPosition][i]); //this is in a loop     
}
```

ANSWER:

Just in case someone finds this and has the same issue.

```
foreach(Datapoint d in chart1.Series[0].Points)  
{  
   if(intCounter % 100 == 0) //I have .1 second increments. I want the datapoint labeled every 10 seconds  
   {  
      d.label = Convert.ToString(time); //i actually used string.format because i have to piece time together.  
   }
   intCounter +=1;  
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of what you've done so far.

Comment: You really should post at least an image of what you want; this is often more helpful than posting code.. - You did add several Series and set their chartType to Line, right? You can set `IsValueShownAsLabel` for any series.. - Or if that would be too much you can set label as needed: `yourSeries.Points[someindex].Label = "asdasdas";`

Comment: Thanks, TaW. Your comment led me in the correct direction. I have way too many datapoints to use IsValueShownAsLabel, though. There were numbers all over my plot from using this.